# mongodb get id as string not as mongoId object on find

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb

lets say i have many documents inside 1 collection that look like this

```
Array
(
    [_id] => MongoId Object
        (
            [$id] => 547b04884a08bb0f201026c2
        )

    [name] => someName
    [description] => someDescription
)
```

what should i do to get return array that looks like this

```
Array
(
    [$id] => 547b04884a08bb0f201026c2
    [name] => someName
)
```

i know i can use something like this $collection->find(array(),  array('name','_id' => array( '$id')));

but that returns me  array with name and mongoId objects which contains variable id and i would like to get up specifed array, so i dont have to extract that id.
can someone please give me an example or point me in right direction what and where to look

Answer (score 0):

For most use cases you can just work directly with the MongoID object as-is.

If you're combining the document's `_id` with other strings for output/display, you can use use it as-is. The MongoID class has a [toString()](http://php.net/manual/en/mongoid.tostring.php) method, which simply returns the raw value of the object as a string.

If you're using the document ID to do further queries against Mongo, you **need** to use a MongoID object anyway, so there is still no point converting it.